# Ruby - search file for a similar word

Tags: ruby, pdf, match, ocr, partial

I have OCR scanned a large number of documents and need to identify a keyword within the scanned files. The problem is, because the OCR is not dependable - for example the word "SUBSCRIPTION" may end up being "SUBSCR|P||ON" - I will need to search for a *near match* rather than a full match.

Does anyone know how I can search a file for the word "SUBSCRIPTION" and return true if an 80% match is found?

Comment: Perhaps the [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) might be useful in this context. There are some implementations of this algorithm on [Rubygems](https://rubygems.org/search?query=Levenshtein).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the gem Amatch, found [here](https://github.com/flori/amatch). This gem implements several distance algorithms. Also, read this other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540581/difference-between-jaro-winkler-and-levenshtein-distance) about the difference between Levenshtein and Jaro distance algorithms and check which one is more suitable for you.

TL;DR, here is a small snippet to help you get started in solving your problem, using the Amatch gem.

```
'subscription'.levenshtein_similar('SUBSCR|P||ON') #=> 0.0
'SUBSCRIPTION'.levenshtein_similar('SUBSCR|P||ON') #=> 0.75
'subscription'.jaro_similar('SUBSCR|P||ON')        #=> 0.83
'SUBSCRIPTION'.jaro_similar('SUBSCR|P||ON')        #=> 0.83
'subscription'.jarowinkler_similar('SUBSCR|P||ON') #=> 0.9
'SUBSCRIPTION'.jarowinkler_similar('SUBSCR|P||ON') #=> 0.9
```

If you want to evaluate if a given text has any occurrences of a word, try this:

```
def occurs?(text, target_word)
  text_words = text.split(' ') # Splits the text into an array of words.
  text_words.each do |word|
    return true if word.jaro_similar(target_word) > 0.8
  end
  false
end

example_text = 'This text has the word SUBSCR|P||ON malformed.'
other_text = 'This text does not.'

occurs?(example_text, 'SUBSCRIPTION') #=> true
occurs?(other_text, 'SUBSCRIPTION')   #=> false
```

Notice that you can call method `#downcase` to the text words too, if you prefer. And you have to parse the text content of your original file first. Hope this helps!