# How to improve comaprison quality when using utl_match.jaro_winkler?

Tags: string, plsql

I use utl_match.jaro_winkler in order to compare company names. In most cases it works fine, but sometimes I get pretty weird results.

This for example returns 0.62:

```
utl_match.jaro_winkler('ГОРОДСКАЯ КЛИНИЧЕСКАЯ БОЛЬНИЦА 18','ДИНА');
```

Those are absolutely different names both by length and symbols! How could it be 62%?

Another example:

```
SELECT utl_match.jaro_winkler('ООО МЕГИ', 'МЕГИ')
```

This returns 0! Despite the fact that those are very similar strings.

It feels like I should use something more complicated and advanced than just `upper()` and  `utl_match.jaro_winkler()`. But I have no idea what exactly.

What would you recommend? What are best practices of comparing two strings? Where I can read about it?

Comment: Thanks Руслан Х.  String comparison is a rich topic.  There are trade-offs among the approaches; domains have different goals and weigh things differently.  For example, in some disciplines, transpositions or inversions can be treated as single operations, despite making strings appear very different.   I would suggest assessing what kind of comparison applies in your situation (phonetic/structural/etc) and what performance tolerances, and evaluate candidates from there.  This has some info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25540581/difference-between-jaro-winkler-and-levenshtein-distance

Comment: Thank you, @alexgibbs! That's interesting.

Comment: I've decided to use utl_match.edit_distance_similarity since it gives much better results